# tkinter window title when using class to hold widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a window title to a tkinter application. The .title('Mytitle') seems to work fine on simple examples, but not where I'm encapsulating the widgets in a class.

Here's a simple example using the "Hello, again" tutorial from www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/

Why does this not work? Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.title('blob')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Try instantiating the App after setting the title. However, this seems to work for me too.

Comment: It works fine for me but obviously, title can't be seen right after starting a script because window is very small. It can be seen only after resizing it. You can add 'root.geometry("500x500")' to make title visible immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Marcin Kowalczyk's comment, the window size is too small to show the title. Curiously, without the widgets the window is expanded to show the title, hence the assumption that it wasn't actually there.